# Is it available to use UIBackgroundModes and bluetooth-central to send a meesage who is in close area?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bluetooth, multitasking

I want to create an Application that will send a message or pop up an alert when an people is using a same Iphone Application. And the requirement is , it also need to pop up an alert even it is in background or in sleep mode.
I found an  function named  UIBackgroundModes and bluetooth-central that will allow to move bluetooth in background.
Somebody help me and i will also be happy if there is sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not while app is in background mode.  For background mode, you will have to fallback to push notification.

Excerpt from Apple Docs:

[Peer-to-Peer Connectivity Provides Local Wireless and Bluetooth Networking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

**Peer-to-peer connectivity** allows your game to create an ad-hoc Bluetooth or local wireless network between multiple iOS-based devices. Although designed with games in mind, this network is useful for any type of data exchange among users of your application. For example, an application could use peer-to-peer connectivity to share electronic business cards or other data.

*Peer-to-peer connectivity is provided in iOS 3.0 and later.*

Comment: Thank you for your information! I success to move the blue tooth on the back ground. But another problem has raised.. I cannot  send/receive data to the connected peer when it is in the background. This is my code